# MongoDB field only accepts 3 special values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design, mongodb-query, nosql

```js
      slider_value: {
        type: Number,
        required: false,
      },
```

This is the Mongoose schema for one of the fields in my MongoDB model.

It may only accept the integer values of `1, 4, and 10`.

How can this validator be specified in the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to store either one of these three values, storing them as a string, and validating using the `enum` key would be reasonable. For example that could look like this:

```js
{
  slider_value: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["1", "4", "10"],
  },
}
```

Alternatively, if it is a requirement to store them in form of an int, you could use a custom validator to check a value before it's saved. That would look like this:

```js
{
  slider_value: {
    type: Number,
    validate: {
      validator: value => value === 1 || value === 4 || value === 10,
      message: props => `${props.value} is invalid for slider_value`,
    },
  },
}
```

For more details on custom validators and validation in mongoose in generell, here are the [mongoose validation docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html).